# C# dynamic object instantiation based on language or CultureInfo

Tags: c#, object, dynamic

I'm looking at implementing a true multi-lingual pluralisation class and I'm basing it on an interface IPlural that I've created.

IPlural defines the function pluralType

```
string pluralType(float value);
```

For every language that I want to support I plan on creating a class file that implements the rule set that determines the pluralType which could be "zero", "one", "two", "few", "many" or "other". The function is simple, you pass a numeric value in, you get a string out.

My issue is that I want to choose one of the implementations of IPlural based on the users current CultureInfo / Language so short of having a massive switch statement how can I go about doing this?

All my classes are called things like:

- Plural_en
- Plural_pl
- Plural_bs

where the last two characters are the language (which in this case is usually locale independent).

These classes all implement IPlural and I envisage that it should work as follows...

```
IPlural pluraliser = new "dynamically chosen pluraliser class"
string pt = pluraliser.pluralType(5);
```

The thing is, I don't know if this is even possible?

Any pointers would be most welcome.

Thanks

Comment: I believe that there are some languages where e.g. 2 has different forms depending on e.g. genders or other modifying forms. How are you planning to address that?

Comment: I think this design of pluralization is very over-simplified, and won't work in the general case; typically, you'll want to localize an entire string into multiple modified forms; also, the number and nature of those forms can be... "quite complex".

Comment: In macedonian, one book is "edna kniga", one dress is "eden fustan", two books are "dve knigi", two dresses are "dva fustani", and three books/dresses are "tri knigi/fustani".

Comment: @SWeko What about five books? In Russian, the plural changes again ("одна книга" vs. "две книги" vs. "пять книг").

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the issues of pluralisation regarding different languages and the solution I'm building has a C# implementation of the Java ChoiceFormat but I'm taking it further with full pluralisation support so I can use resx files with custom formatting to deliver accurate phraseology in any language. At least that's the plan...

Comment: I should add that I plan on implementing the pluralisation classes based on the rulesets defined here http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html

Comment: For a further explanation of where I'm going with this, check out this question (now fully answered) I asked a couple of weeks ago.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18231828/net-equivalent-of-choices-in-java-resource-bundles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two relatively easy solutions:

- Use a `Dictionary<string,Func<IPlural>>` to construct `Plural_..` classes, or
- Use reflection to locate the class named according to your convention.

Here is how you can implement the first solution:

```
private readonly IDictionary<string,Func<IPlural>> LangToPlural =
    new Dictionary<string,Func<IPlural>> {
        {"en", () => new Plural_en()}
    ,   {"pl", () => new Plural_pl()}
    ,   {"bs", () => new Plural_bs()}
    ,   ...
    };
public IPlural MakePluralForLanguageCode(string langCode) {
    Func<IPlural> res;
    if (LangToPlural.TryGetValue(langCode, out res)) {
        return res();
    }
    return new Plural_en(); // Provide a default
}
```

Here is how you can implement the second solution:

```
var typeName = typeof(IPlural).Assembly.FullName.+".Plural_"+langCode;
var plType = Type.GetType(typeName);
if (plType == null) retunr new Plural_en(); // Provide a default
var constr = plType.GetConstructor(new Type[0]);
return (IPlural)constr.Invoke(new Type[0]);
```

The advantage of the first method is its simplicity; the advantage of the second method is its ability to pick up additional implementations of `Plural_xy` as they become available, without requiring any further modifications to your code.

Comment: Hadn't thought about using reflection. We've already got an object factory for the main architecture of the system but it doesn't quite fit the language requirement question but reflection does the job very nicely indeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is called the [Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_Pattern)

You can have a class called `PluralizerFactory`, that would do:

```
public static IPlural CreatePluralizer(string language)
{
  if (language=="en")
    return new Plural_en();
  if (language=="pl")
    return new Plural_pl();
  if (language=="bs")
    return new Plural_bs();
  throw new ArgumentException("invalid language");
}
```

This can than be used

```
IPlural pluraliser = PluralizerFactory.CreatePluralizer("en");
string pt = pluraliser.pluralType(5);
```

The code in the `CreatePluralizer` method can be as ugly or as clever as you like it. The important thing is that your calling code is shielded from it, so the calling code need not even know that there exist different classes for "en" and "pl".

This implementation is among the simplest and the ugliest, but it's representative of how it could be done.